# replacing one of the sublist element with new element using .remove() and .append() in python

Tags: python, append, sublist

```
subjects = ["Algorithms", "Software Design", "Poetry", "Electronics"] 
grades = ["98", "88", "85", "90"]
print("Course  ", "  Score")
gradebook = zip(subjects, grades)
for subject, grade in gradebook: #for creating a table
    print(subject, '\t', grade)
print('\n')
grade_book = list(gradebook)
list(grade_book[2]).remove('85')
list(grade_book[2]).append('Pass')
```

Here I have a sublist as ['Poetry', '85'], and I have to delete the grade(85) by using remove() and by using the .append() add a new "Pass" value to the sublist where the 85 is located. I tried it in the last two lines, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

zip return a list of tuple. Once a tuple is created, you cannot change its values.

1. create a new tuple, and replace it
2. turn it to a list, change, re-tuple it

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list of tuples into a list of lists instead and the edit

```
grade_book = [list(elem) for elem in gradebook]
grade_book[2][1] = 'Pass'
```

If you need to convert back to a list of tuples you can do so like this

```
grade_book = [(x,y) for [x,y] in grade_book]
```

A dictionary might also be a nice option here.

Answer (score 0):

`zip(subjects, grades)` returns an iterator. By looping through `gradebook` you already "use up" all the values in the iterator. That's why `grade_book = list(gradebook)` returns an empty list, thus making the following operations invalid.

I would also suggest to use a dictionary here, like so:

```
subjects = ["Algorithms", "Software Design", "Poetry", "Electronics"] 
grades = ["98", "88", "85", "90"]
gradebook = dict(zip(subjects, grades))
print("Course  ", "  Score")
for subject, grade in gradebook.items(): # for creating a table
    print(subject, '\t', grade)
print()
```

Then you can easily add new elements and use .pop() to remove elements:

```
gradebook.pop('Poetry')
gradebook["Pass"] = "85"
```